# Reliability of Google Analytics data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have developed an **iOS** game and currently the game is in beta phase. I have integrated **Google Analytics (GA**) to understand the users' behavior. I am distributing the game to my beta testers using **TestFlight**.

Recently, I found that number of sessions shown by TestFlight data is not matching with that of GA's data.

I have following questions:

1. Is GA's data is more **reliable** than the TestFlight's data?
2. Is GA suitable analytics solution for mobile games? If not, what are the reasons for that? Is **Firebase** analytics more reliable compared to GA?
3. I am looking for an analytics solution which can help to analyze behavior of each user (per user tracking instead of aggregated data). Can Firebase analytics provide this feature?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GA and Firebase are different Analytical solutions from Google.

Firebase targets native mobile apps (Android and iOS) whereas GA is designed for predominantly for web tracking that includes sessions and page views.

Since you need to track data for iOS game app designed and developed using Unity, most appropriate solution would be to make use of the [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start). Firebase also exposes various [set of APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/analytics/firebase-analytics) that you would need to track user events of your app. Please note that most of the significant events are [collected automatically](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484) by the SDK.